# Dimension of weights and bias for binary classification in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

We're using the MLPClassifier in sklearn.neural_network and do some analysis on the bias and weights generated by the classifier.

There is a problem when we have binary data, i.e. only two values are allowed. Then it seems like dimension of the last layer is 1, not 2. 
In other cases it seems like the shape of the bias and weight always match the number of of output values.

```py
binary_classifier= MLPClassifier().fit(np.matrix([[0.], [1.]]), np.array([0,1]))
other_classifier = MLPClassifier().fit(np.matrix([[0.], [1.], [2]]), np.array([0,1,2]))

# Note that the dimension below is 1
print(binary_classifier.intercepts_[-1].shape, binary_classifier.coefs_[-1].shape)
# Note that the dimension below is 3
print(other_classifier.intercepts_[-1].shape, other_classifier.coefs_[-1].shape)
```

Output:

```
(1,) (100, 1)
(3,) (100, 3)
```

It makes sense mathematically that you can do this and I assume it is an optimization, but we loose generalizability. 
Is there an easy way to prevent scikit from doing this? How can we otherwise convert the weights and bias so that their dimensions match the number of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class labels for neural networks require one hot encoding, and this happens under the hood of the `MLPClassifier`. If you explicitly pass in a one hot encoded target then you get the desired output:

```
#Now one hot encoded
binary_classifier= MLPClassifier().fit(np.matrix([[0.], [1.]]), np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]))
# NOT encoded
other_classifier = MLPClassifier().fit(np.matrix([[0.], [1.], [2]]), np.array([0,1,2]))

# Note that the dimension below is 2
print(binary_classifier.intercepts_[-1].shape, binary_classifier.coefs_[-1].shape)
# Note that the dimension below is 3
print(other_classifier.intercepts_[-1].shape, other_classifier.coefs_[-1].shape)
```

**Ouput:**

```
((2,), (100, 2))
((3,), (100, 3))
```

For more information on how to perform this preprocessing step I would take a look at the `OneHotEncoder` [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) in scikit.